# Seeking algo for text diff that detects and can group similar lines

Tags: algorithm, text, diff, levenshtein-distance

I am in the process of writing a diff text tool to compare two similar source code files.

There are many such "diff" tools around, but mine shall be a little improved:

If it finds a set of lines are mismatched on both sides (ie. in both files), it shall not only highlight those lines but also highlight the individual changes in these lines (I call this inter-line comparison here).

An example of my somewhat working solution:

[alt text http://files.tempel.org/tmp/diff_example.png](http://files.tempel.org/tmp/diff_example.png)

What it currently does is to take a set of mismatched lines and running their single chars thru the diff algo once more, producing the pink highlighting.

However, the second set of mismatches, containing "original 2", requires more work: Here, the first two right lines ("added line a/b") were added, while the third line is an altered version of the left side. I wish my software to detect this difference between a likely alteration and a probable new line.

When looking at this simple example, I can rather easily detect this case:

With an algo such as Levenshtein, I could find that of all right lines in the set of 3 to 5, line 5 matches left line 3 best, thus I could deduct that lines 3 and 4 on the right were added, and perform the inter-line comparison on left line 3 and right line 5.

So far, so good. But I am still stuck with how to turn this into a more general algorithm for this purpose.

In a more complex situation, a set of different lines could have added lines on both sides, with a few closely matching lines in between. This gets quite complicated:

I'd have to match not only the first line on the left to the best on the right, but vice versa as well, and so on with all other lines. Basically, I have to match every line on the left against every one on the right. At worst, this might create even crossings, so that it's not easily clear any more which lines were newly inserted and which were just altered (Note: I do not want to deal with possible moved lines in such a block, unless that would actually simplify the algorithm).

Sure, this is never going to be perfect, but I'm trying to get it better than it's now. Any suggestions that aren't too theoerical but rather practical (I'm not good understanding abstract algos) are appreciated.

***Update***

I must admit that I do not even understand how the LCS algo works. I simply feed it two arrays of strings and out comes a list of which sequences do not match. I am basically using the code from here: http://www.incava.org/projects/java/java-diff

Looking at the code I find one function equal() that is responsible for telling the algorithm whether two lines match or not. Based on what Pavel suggested, I wonder if that's the place where I'd make the changes. But how? This function only returns a boolean - not a relative value that could identify the quality of the match. And I can not simply used a fixed Levenshtein ration that would decide whether a similar line is still considered equal or not - I'll need something that's self-adopting to the entire set of lines in question.

So, what I'm basically saying is that I still do not understand where I'd apply the fuzzy value that relates to the relative similarity of lines that do not (exactly) match.

Comment: If you want to to create a tool better than the exisiting diff tools, pick the one you think is best, understand and try to improve it. Starting from scratch is unlikely to beat the reasonably decent ones, let alone the best.

Comment: Can you recommend any that do this as I like it already, so that I can use them as a reference? I work on OSX, and I haven't find one yet that does this as well.

Comment: You should be able to find the source code for 'diff' on the web, found on most Unix systems.

Comment: It appears you do not understand the problem, as the standard diff tool doesn't do at all what I need, at least not in one go: all it does is to tell me what matches and what not. But I have a "fuzzy" factor in here, and I've not found anything like that handling in the diff source codes I've looked at.

Comment: See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer for a tool that identifies small fragments within lines that differ.

Comment: Python difflib already does this "inter-line" comparison, might be a place to start.  http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With an algo such as Levenshtein, I could find that of all right lines in the set of 3 to 5, line 5 matches left line 3 best, thus I could deduct that lines 3 and 4 on the right were added, and perform the inter-line comparison on left line 3 and right line 5.

After you have determined it, use the *same* algorithm to determine what lines in these two chinks match each other.  But you need to make slight modificaiton.  When you used the algorithm to match equal lines, the lines could either match or not match, so that added either 0 or 1 to the cell of the table you used.

When comparing strings in one chunk some of them are "more equal" than others (ack. to Orwell).  So they can add a real number from 0 to 1 to the cell when considering what sequence matches best so far.

To compute this metrics (from 0 to 1), you can apply to each pair of strings you encounter... right, the same algorithm again (actually, you already did this when you were doing the *first* pass of Levenstein algorithm).  This will compute the length of LCS, whose ratio to the average length of two strings would be the the metric value.

Or, you can borrow the algorithm from one of diff tools.  For instance, `vimdiff` can highlight the matches you require.

Comment: Hmm, you mean to apply the LCS algo to the "similarity" rating? Yes, that sounds like it could work. I'll have to give this some more thought. Thanks for now.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, I mean that.  I actually implemented the same technique in production code and it appeared to be a bit slow, but solving the task.

Answer (score 3):

Levenshtein distance is based on the notion of an "edit script" that transforms one string into another.  It's very closely related to the [Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) used for aligning DNA sequences by inserting gap characters, in which we search for the alignment that maximises a score in O(*nm*) time using dynamic programming.  Exact matches between characters increase the score, while mismatches or inserted gap characters reduce the score.  An example alignment of `AACTTGCCA` and `AATGCGAT`:

```
AACTTGCCA-
AA-T-GCGAT
(6 matches, 1 mismatch, 3 gap characters, 3 gap regions)
```

We can think of the top string being the "starting" sequence that we are transforming into the "final" sequence on the bottom.  Each column containing a `-` gap character on the bottom is a deletion, each column with a `-` on the top is an insertion, and each column with different (non-gap) characters is a substitution.  There are 2 deletions, 1 insertion and 1 substitution in the above alignment, so the Levenshtein distance is 4.

Here is another alignment of the same strings, with the same Levenshtein distance:

```
AACTTGCCA-
AA--TGCGAT
(6 matches, 1 mismatch, 3 gap characters, 2 gap regions)
```

But notice that although there are the same number of gaps, there is one less gap *region*.  Because biological processes are more likely to create wide gaps than multiple separate gaps, biologists prefer this alignment -- *and so will the users of your program*.  This is accomplished by **also penalising the number of gap regions** in the scores that we compute.  An O(*nm*) algorithm to accomplish this for strings of lengths *n* and *m* was given by Gotoh in 1982 in a paper called "An improved algorithm for matching biological sequences".  Unfortunately, I can't find any links to free full text of the paper -- but there are many useful tutorials that you can find by googling "sequence alignment" and "affine gap penalty".

In general, different choices of match, mismatch, gap and gap region weights will give different alignments, but any negative score for gap regions will prefer the bottom alignment above to the top one.

**What does all this have to do with your problem?**  If you use Gotoh's algorithm on individual characters with a suitable gap penalty (arrived at with a few empirical tests), you should find a significant decrease in the the number of terrible-looking alignments like the example you gave.

### Efficiency Considerations

Ideally, you could just do this on characters and ignore lines altogether, since the affine penalty will work to cluster changes into blocks spanning many lines wherever it can.  But because of the higher running time, it may be more realistic to do a first pass on lines and then rerun the algorithm on characters, using as input all lines that are not identical.  Under this scheme, any shared block of identical lines can be handled by compressing it into a single "character" with inflated matching weight, which helps to ensure no "crossings" appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution someone else just made me realize:

My original approach was like this:

1. Split the text up into separate lines and use LCS algo to determine where there are blocks of nonmatching lines.
2. Use some smart algo (which this question is about) to figure out which of these lines closely match, i.e. to tell that these lines were modified between revisions.
3. Compare those closely matching lines line-by-line using LCS again, while marking the non-matching lines as entirely new.

While this would allow for a better visual display of changes when comparing source code revisions, I now found that a much simpler approach is usually sufficient. It works like this:

1. Same as above.
2. Take the right and left block of nonmatching lines, concatenate those lines, and tokenize them (either into language-specific tokens/words, or just into single characters)
3. Apply the LCS algo on the two arrays of tokens.

Maybe those who replied to my original question assumed that I knew to do this all the time, but I had my focus so strongly on a per-line comparison that it did not occur to me to apply LCS on the set of lines by concatenating them, instead of processing them line-by-line.

So, while this approach will not provide as detailed change information as my original intent was, it still does improve the results over what I started yesterday with when I wrote this question.

I'll leave this question open for a while longer - maybe someone else, reading all this, can still provide a complete answer (Pavel and random_hacker offered some suggestions, but it's not a complete solution yet - anyway, thank you for the helpful comments).